# How to call JSON filesystem structure in HTML file and javascript

Tags: filesystems

I have the following JSON file. I am wondering how can I call the files in the HTML file specially that there is a documents in some documents.

```
{
"d_type": "directory", 
"name": ".", 
"size": 1020, 
"subdirectory": [
  {
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": ".DS_Store", 
  "size": 15364
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "animation.py", 
  "size": 928
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "cat.png", 
  "size": 12574
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "courses.json", 
  "size": 714
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "courses.py", 
  "size": 827
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "Courses.xlsx", 
  "size": 37894
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "data.json", 
  "size": 356
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "directoryTree.py", 
  "size": 452
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "excelMani.py", 
  "size": 753
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "exceltojson.py", 
  "size": 699
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "filesystem.json", 
  "size": 0
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "guess.py", 
  "size": 621
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "hello.py", 
  "size": 107
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "imtools.py", 
  "size": 115
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "input.py", 
  "size": 184
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "jsonFileOut.py", 
  "size": 705
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "listFilesAndDirectories.py", 
  "size": 521
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "memoryGame.py", 
  "size": 9368
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "os.py", 
  "size": 156
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "osout.py", 
  "size": 185
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "output.json", 
  "size": 28816
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "output.txt", 
  "size": 42385
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "pygameDrawing.py", 
  "size": 1001
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "pygameHello.py", 
  "size": 304
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "rsa.py", 
  "size": 198
}, 
{
  "d_type": "directory", 
  "name": "simplejson-3.6.5", 
  "size": 578, 
  "subdirectory": [
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": ".DS_Store", 
      "size": 12292
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "build", 
      "size": 170, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "directory", 
          "name": "bdist.macosx-10.9-intel", 
          "size": 68, 
          "subdirectory": []
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "directory", 
          "name": "lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7", 
          "size": 102, 
          "subdirectory": [
            {
              "d_type": "directory", 
              "name": "simplejson", 
              "size": 374, 
              "subdirectory": [
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "__init__.py", 
                  "size": 23137
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "_speedups.so", 
                  "size": 92976
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "compat.py", 
                  "size": 1036
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "decoder.py", 
                  "size": 14721
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "encoder.py", 
                  "size": 25280
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "ordered_dict.py", 
                  "size": 3370
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "scanner.py", 
                  "size": 4653
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "directory", 
                  "name": "tests", 
                  "size": 986, 
                  "subdirectory": [
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "__init__.py", 
                      "size": 3029
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_bigint_as_string.py", 
                      "size": 2238
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_bitsize_int_as_string.py", 
                      "size": 2297
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_check_circular.py", 
                      "size": 917
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_decimal.py", 
                      "size": 2544
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_decode.py", 
                      "size": 4021
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_default.py", 
                      "size": 221
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_dump.py", 
                      "size": 4999
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_encode_basestring_ascii.py", 
                      "size": 2337
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_encode_for_html.py", 
                      "size": 1022
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_errors.py", 
                      "size": 1549
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_fail.py", 
                      "size": 6346
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_float.py", 
                      "size": 1430
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_for_json.py", 
                      "size": 2767
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_indent.py", 
                      "size": 2568
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_item_sort_key.py", 
                      "size": 1127
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_namedtuple.py", 
                      "size": 4004
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_pass1.py", 
                      "size": 1746
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_pass2.py", 
                      "size": 386
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_pass3.py", 
                      "size": 482
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_recursion.py", 
                      "size": 1679
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_scanstring.py", 
                      "size": 7311
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_separators.py", 
                      "size": 942
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_speedups.py", 
                      "size": 1011
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_tool.py", 
                      "size": 2853
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_tuple.py", 
                      "size": 1922
                    }, 
                    {
                      "d_type": "file", 
                      "name": "test_unicode.py", 
                      "size": 6996
                    }
                  ]
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "tool.py", 
                  "size": 1136
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "directory", 
          "name": "temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7", 
          "size": 102, 
          "subdirectory": [
            {
              "d_type": "directory", 
              "name": "simplejson", 
              "size": 102, 
              "subdirectory": [
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "_speedups.o", 
                  "size": 268464
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "CHANGES.txt", 
      "size": 17448
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "conf.py", 
      "size": 5681
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "dist", 
      "size": 102, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "simplejson-3.6.5-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg", 
          "size": 143523
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "index.rst", 
      "size": 38920
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "LICENSE.txt", 
      "size": 10375
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "MANIFEST.in", 
      "size": 82
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "PKG-INFO", 
      "size": 2735
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "README.rst", 
      "size": 1412
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "scripts", 
      "size": 102, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "make_docs.py", 
          "size": 420
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "setup.cfg", 
      "size": 59
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "setup.py", 
      "size": 3811
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "simplejson", 
      "size": 408, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": ".DS_Store", 
          "size": 6148
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "__init__.py", 
          "size": 23137
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "_speedups.c", 
          "size": 106976
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "compat.py", 
          "size": 1036
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "decoder.py", 
          "size": 14721
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "encoder.py", 
          "size": 25280
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "ordered_dict.py", 
          "size": 3370
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "scanner.py", 
          "size": 4653
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "directory", 
          "name": "tests", 
          "size": 1020, 
          "subdirectory": [
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": ".DS_Store", 
              "size": 12292
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "__init__.py", 
              "size": 3029
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_bigint_as_string.py", 
              "size": 2238
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_bitsize_int_as_string.py", 
              "size": 2297
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_check_circular.py", 
              "size": 917
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_decimal.py", 
              "size": 2544
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_decode.py", 
              "size": 4021
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_default.py", 
              "size": 221
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_dump.py", 
              "size": 4999
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_encode_basestring_ascii.py", 
              "size": 2337
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_encode_for_html.py", 
              "size": 1022
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_errors.py", 
              "size": 1549
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_fail.py", 
              "size": 6346
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_float.py", 
              "size": 1430
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_for_json.py", 
              "size": 2767
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_indent.py", 
              "size": 2568
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_item_sort_key.py", 
              "size": 1127
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_namedtuple.py", 
              "size": 4004
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_pass1.py", 
              "size": 1746
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_pass2.py", 
              "size": 386
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_pass3.py", 
              "size": 482
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_recursion.py", 
              "size": 1679
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_scanstring.py", 
              "size": 7311
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_separators.py", 
              "size": 942
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_speedups.py", 
              "size": 1011
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_tool.py", 
              "size": 2853
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_tuple.py", 
              "size": 1922
            }, 
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "test_unicode.py", 
              "size": 6996
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "tool.py", 
          "size": 1136
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "simplejson.egg-info", 
      "size": 204, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "dependency_links.txt", 
          "size": 1
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "PKG-INFO", 
          "size": 2735
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "SOURCES.txt", 
          "size": 1357
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "top_level.txt", 
          "size": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  "d_type": "file", 
  "name": "test.xlsx", 
  "size": 34682
}, 
{
  "d_type": "directory", 
  "name": "xlrd-0.9.3", 
  "size": 340, 
  "subdirectory": [
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": ".DS_Store", 
      "size": 6148
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "build", 
      "size": 136, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "directory", 
          "name": "lib", 
          "size": 102, 
          "subdirectory": [
            {
              "d_type": "directory", 
              "name": "xlrd", 
              "size": 476, 
              "subdirectory": [
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "__init__.py", 
                  "size": 21105
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "biffh.py", 
                  "size": 17511
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "book.py", 
                  "size": 56979
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "compdoc.py", 
                  "size": 21235
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "formatting.py", 
                  "size": 45335
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "formula.py", 
                  "size": 94301
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "info.py", 
                  "size": 22
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "licences.py", 
                  "size": 3406
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "sheet.py", 
                  "size": 107386
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "timemachine.py", 
                  "size": 1773
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "xldate.py", 
                  "size": 7895
                }, 
                {
                  "d_type": "file", 
                  "name": "xlsx.py", 
                  "size": 31809
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "directory", 
          "name": "scripts-2.7", 
          "size": 102, 
          "subdirectory": [
            {
              "d_type": "file", 
              "name": "runxlrd.py", 
              "size": 16300
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "PKG-INFO", 
      "size": 994
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "README.html", 
      "size": 4672
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "scripts", 
      "size": 102, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "runxlrd.py", 
          "size": 16304
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "file", 
      "name": "setup.py", 
      "size": 1887
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "tests", 
      "size": 918, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "__init__.py", 
          "size": 0
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "base.py", 
          "size": 118
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "Formate.xls", 
          "size": 10752
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "formula_test_names.xls", 
          "size": 7680
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "formula_test_sjmachin.xls", 
          "size": 16896
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "issue20.xls", 
          "size": 6144
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "merged_cells.xlsx", 
          "size": 9275
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "picture_in_cell.xls", 
          "size": 6656
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "profiles.xls", 
          "size": 33792
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "ragged.xls", 
          "size": 6656
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "reveng1.xlsx", 
          "size": 16683
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_biffh.py", 
          "size": 574
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_cell.py", 
          "size": 2328
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_comments_excel.xlsx", 
          "size": 15803
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_comments_gdocs.xlsx", 
          "size": 4187
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_formats.py", 
          "size": 3039
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_formulas.py", 
          "size": 2323
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_open_workbook.py", 
          "size": 1294
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_sheet.py", 
          "size": 4238
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_workbook.py", 
          "size": 1483
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_xldate.py", 
          "size": 2384
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_xldate_to_datetime.py", 
          "size": 6128
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "test_xlsx_comments.py", 
          "size": 1517
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "text_bar.xlsx", 
          "size": 8196
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "xf_class.xls", 
          "size": 23040
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "d_type": "directory", 
      "name": "xlrd", 
      "size": 850, 
      "subdirectory": [
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "__init__.py", 
          "size": 21105
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "__init__.pyc", 
          "size": 3397
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "biffh.py", 
          "size": 17511
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "biffh.pyc", 
          "size": 15336
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "book.py", 
          "size": 56979
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "book.pyc", 
          "size": 37567
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "compdoc.py", 
          "size": 21235
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "compdoc.pyc", 
          "size": 13729
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "xldate.pyc", 
          "size": 5654
        }, 
        {
          "d_type": "file", 
          "name": "xlsx.py", 
          "size": 31809
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I want to call the files in html file. I can't use ng-repeat because in the json file, there is documents inside documents. 
I wrote a JSON file, which contains files and document. so I want to represent them in which when i press on subdirectory, it shows the other subdirectory and files inside ! and so on..! I hope u understand my point :) !